# How can I combine(concatenate) two data frames with the same column name in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Can I append a dataframe to the right of other dataframe having same column names

Comment: You mean joining dataframes or merging dataframes?

Comment: i mean just appending a dataframe at right, not joining

Comment: What do you mean by right? show me some example data what you are looking?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can join two dataframes like this.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.col("column").equalTo(df2("column")));
```

If you are looking for Union, then you can do something like this.

```
df1.unionAll(df2);  // spark 1.6
```

Spark 2.0, `unionAll` was renamed to [`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#union(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset))

Comment: but unionAll requires same number of columns for dataframes.

Comment: Union fails unless you have a bug that was fixed in May 2019.  Any better ways for people stuck in old systems?  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21109

Comment: if the join columns have the same name, it is enought to write this:

val res = df1.join(df2, "column")

Comment: @Zvonko that would lead to having duplicate columns in the resulting dataframe.