# In Spark-Scala application involving Join, att what point should we convert Dataframe to Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

In our Spark-Scala application, we want to use typed Datasets. There is a JOIN operation. There is a join between `DF1 & DF2 (DF - Dataframe)`.

My question is should we convert DF1 & DF2 both to `Dataset[T]` and then perform `JOIN` or should we do the `JOIN` and then convert the result `DataFrame` to `Dataset`.

As I understand since here `Dataset[T]` are being used for type safety so we should convert DF1 & DF2 to `Dataset[T]`. Can someone please confirm and advise if something is not correct?

Comment: Conceptually, consider DataFrame as an alias for a collection of generic objects Dataset[Row], where a Row is a generic untyped JVM object. Dataset, by contrast, is a collection of strongly-typed JVM objects, dictated by a case class you define in Scala or a class in Java.

Comment: This question related maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397206/how-can-i-combineconcatenate-two-data-frames-with-the-same-column-name-in-java

Comment: No. that question doesn't help. My question was should I convert both the DataFrames to Dataset[T] before JOIN or should I convert the result of JOIN to Dataset[T]

Comment: I see. Did you try to check the time of process when doing the both solution?

Comment: I think both solution is okay,  But try to check to check if there is difference on processing time and if not then both solution is good.

Comment: Considering that typed joins [don't even type check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40605167/10938362) I'd say at no point at all.

Comment: I have coded both i.e. joins with Typed Datasets and DataFrames; will test those and see the performance.