# How do I concatenate the two pyspark dataframes produced by my loop logic?

Tags: pyspark

I have looked at similar questions and answers in stack overflow but the loop aspect of my issue poses a challenge that I can't figure out.

I am trying to to concatenate the output of some code that loops through the different products in the below spark dataframe and selects specific products such as 12 and 2 month subscriptions.

I have this spark dataframe (df)

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|227729        |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2  months of global news|
|228544        |2018-04-28 17:01:16|18 months of global news|
|231795        |2018-06-11 20:27:48|36 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
|237883        |2018-08-07 18:52:53|1 months of global news | 
|237924        |2018-08-08 01:31:13|6 months of global news |
|238892        |2018-08-14 02:45:51|9 months of global news |
|242200        |2018-08-19 21:22:05|3 months of global news |
|242413        |2018-08-21 06:26:57|13 months of global news|
|249034        |2018-10-11 15:01:06|16 months of global news|
|254415        |2018-12-28 12:13:18|16 months of global news|
|256866        |2019-02-02 16:34:41|36 months of global news|
|257317        |2019-02-09 18:49:12|11 months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

This is my function to select products called '12 months of global news' for example

```
def renewals(df, n):
    prod_type = str(n)+' months of firecracker md'
    df_first_xmo = df[df['product']== prod_type]
    return df_first_xmo.show()
```

If I run the function I get the desired results:

```
renewals(df, 12)
```

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

If I loop through multiple months (as I did in pandas) it will produce two unnamed dataframes:

```
temp=[]
month = [12, 2]
for x in month:
    temp.append(renewals(all_direct_renew, x))
```

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|227729        |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2  months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

I am trying to figure out how to concatenate the above output in to one spark dataframe. In pandas I could do this by running:

```
foo = pd.concat(temp)
foo
```

```
user_id     purch_date_all          product 
226575      2018-04-04 17:41:23     12 months of global news
234206      2018-07-19 00:52:10     12 months of global news
234607      2018-07-23 20:41:47     12 months of global news
235133      2018-07-30 02:34:58     12 months of global news
227729      2018-04-19 16:50:09     2 months of global news
```

How can change my loop logic to concatenate the output in to one dataframe (such as I did with pandas) and show it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine(concatenate) two data frames with the same column name in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397206/how-can-i-combineconcatenate-two-data-frames-with-the-same-column-name-in-java)

Comment: I looked at that and some similar ones. I may be approaching this entirely wrong. Part of my issue is that as I loop through the months it appends the data to temp. So I don't grasp how to concatenate the output as I don't have named dataframes. The data is appended to temp.

Answer (score 1):

If the column names are the same you can use **union**.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (226575,'2018-04-04 17:41:23','12 months of global news'),
        (234206,'2018-07-19 00:52:10','12 months of global news' ),
        (234607,'2018-07-23 20:41:47','12 months of global news'),
        (235133,'2018-07-30 02:34:58','12 months of global news')
       
    ], 
    ['user_id','purchase_date_all', 'product' ]
)
df.show(truncate=False)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (227729,'2018-04-19 16:50:09','2 months of global news')
       
    ], 
    ['user_id','purchase_date_all', 'product' ]
)
df2.show()

/*
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id|purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575 |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206 |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607 |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133 |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+

+-------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|user_id|purchase_date_all  |product                |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|227729 |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2 months of global news|
+-------+-------------------+-----------------------+
*/

df.union(df2).show()

/*
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id|purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575 |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206 |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607 |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133 |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
|227729 |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2 months of global news |
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+
*/
```

Comment: My issue is how I am producing the dataframes from a loop. ```temp=[]
month = [12, 2]
for x in month:
    temp.append(renewals2(all_direct_renew, x))```  So I don't have two dataframes per se like df1 and df2. Instead I have temp where I appended two dataframes to form the loop. Without appending the second dataframe the loop logic would simply replace the first dataframe in temp.  I can't figure out to make the output one dataframe. Do you see what I mean? How do I union what is in temp?  I need to understand how to concatenate or union via the loop logic somehow.

Comment: You'll have to convert your output to rdds and then you could do something like that with lambda function.